# How to let Boost::random and Matlab produce the same random numbers

Tags: c++, matlab, boost

To check my C++ code, I would like to be able to let Boost::Random and Matlab produce the same random numbers.

So for Boost I use the code:

```
boost::mt19937 var(static_cast<unsigned> (std::time(0)));
boost::uniform_int<> dist(1, 6);
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<> > die(var, dist);
die.engine().seed(0);     
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    std::cout << die() << " ";
}      
std::cout    << std::endl;
```

Which produces (every run of the program):
`4 4 5 6 4 6 4 6 3 4`

And for matlab I use:

```
RandStream.setDefaultStream(RandStream('mt19937ar','seed',0));
randi(6,1,10)
```

Which produces (every run of the program):
`5     6     1     6     4     1     2     4     6     6`

Which is bizarre, since both use the same algorithm, and same seed.
What do I miss?

It seems that Python (using numpy) and Matlab seems comparable, in the random uniform numbers:
Matlab

RandStream.setDefaultStream(RandStream('mt19937ar','seed',203));rand(1,10)

`0.8479    0.1889    0.4506    0.6253    0.9697    0.2078    0.5944    0.9115    0.2457    0.7743`

Python: 
random.seed(203);random.random(10)

`array([ 0.84790006,  0.18893843,  0.45060688,  0.62534723,  0.96974765,
        0.20780668,  0.59444858,  0.91145688,  0.24568615,  0.77430378])`

C++Boost

`0.8479 0.667228 0.188938 0.715892 0.450607 0.0790326 0.625347 0.972369 0.969748 0.858771`

Which is identical to ever other Python and Matlab value...

Comment: Why don't you just generate a random stream either in C or MATLAB, store it on a file, and access it through both the environments?

Comment: I think that you should not feed Boost whit time(0).

Comment: @ntt, that is a possibility but for me not favourable, it seems really a hack.

Comment: @ralu, Ok, thanks for the tip, but even without that init results are exactly similar

Comment: At least figure out if multiple runs whit same init produce same results each time for each function. As far as I know MT uses own seed generator.

Comment: @ralu Done (of course) this yields every run the same output. I'll clearify the text

Comment: @Thomas Well it depends on what (and how) you're trying to test.. But, basically if you just need both the pieces of code (MATLAB and C++) to have the exact same set of 'random' sequence as an input, that method can work.. You can generate it as many times as you want.. Might not be a great idea for deployment, but just to test out your code that would guarantee that the inputs are equal.

Comment: @ntt, True, you are right it is an easy solution. Though I prefer the solution given by Fezvez, and have implemented that random algorithm myself. Thanks for your comments, and it is not meant for deployment at all, just testing and nothing cryptographic ;-)

Comment: @Thomas. Agreed that for the least this helps to understand how the pseudo random number generators work.. I agree I shouldn't stifle curiosity and creativity!! Enjoy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to agree with the other answers, stating that these generators are not "absolute". They may produce different results according to the implementation. I think the simplest solution would be to implement your own generator. It might look daunting (Mersenne twister sure is by the way) but take a look at [Xorshift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift), an extremely simple though powerful one. I copy the C implementation given in the Wikipedia link :

```
uint32_t xor128(void) {
  static uint32_t x = 123456789;
  static uint32_t y = 362436069;
  static uint32_t z = 521288629;
  static uint32_t w = 88675123;
  uint32_t t;

  t = x ^ (x << 11);
  x = y; y = z; z = w;
  return w = w ^ (w >> 19) ^ (t ^ (t >> 8));
}
```

To have the same seed, just put any values you want int x,y,z,w (except(0,0,0,0) I believe). You just need to be sure that Matlab and C++ use both 32 bit for these unsigned int.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed easy to implement. I'll use this for testing, unless someone knows an easy off the shelve approach. Cheers Thomas

Comment: This seems the easiest way to solve it. I've implemented the method (+ a method for uniform and intergers) in both Matlab and C++. Basic, but for basic testing absolutely good enough. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using the interface like

```
randi(6,1,10)
```

will apply some kind of transformation on the raw result of the random generator. This transformation **[is *not* trivial in general](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx)** and Matlab will almost certainly do a different selection step than Boost.

Try comparing raw data streams from the RNGs - chances are they are the same

Comment: Unforutnately also the outputs of rand seems different (I dont know how to get raw output from Matlab). It is a pity. But much more complex then I thought/hoped. I'll switch to another approach.

Answer (score 3):

In case this helps anyone interested in the question:

In order to the get the same behavior for the Twister algorithm:

1. Download the file
   http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/MT2002/CODES/mt19937ar.c
2. Try the following:

   ```
   #include <stdint.h>

   // mt19937ar.c content..

   int main(void)
   {
       int i;
       uint32_t seed = 100;
       init_genrand(seed);
       for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
           printf("%.20f\n",genrand_res53());
       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. Make sure the same values are generated within matlab:

   ```
   RandStream.setGlobalStream( RandStream.create('mt19937ar','seed',100) );
   rand(100,1)
   ```
4. `randi()` seems to be simply `ceil( rand()*maxval )`

Comment: +1 MATLAB [internally uses](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/119520#302137) `genrand_res53` to randomly generate floating-point numbers between 0 and 1. In fact this function calls `genrand_int32` twice (two 32-bit integers) to build its output, which explains why OP sees same numbers every other value compared to Boost. The reason to use `genrand_res53` as opposed to `genrand_real2` is that it gives numbers with more resolution (53-bit). MATLAB, Octave, NumPy, and probably other frameworks are all based on the reference implementation of "Nishimura & Matsumoto".

Comment: In MATLAB, all builtin RNG functions (`rand`, `randn`, `randi`) are implemented in terms of `genrand_res53` (at least that's the case for the default generator), and they share the same underlying *random stream*. `randi` is equivalent to `ceil(rand()*maxVal)`, while `randn` uses the Ziggurat transformation method on top of the default mt19937ar generator. Of course MATLAB has other PRNG methods besides Mersenne Twister: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-controlling-a-random-number-stream.html#brvku_2. btw setting the seed in MATLAB can be simplified as: `rng(100)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Fezvez's answer I've written xor128 in matlab:

```
function [ w, state ] = xor128( state )
%XOR128 implementation of Xorshift
%   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift
%   A starting state might be [123456789, 362436069, 521288629, 88675123]

  x = state(1);
  y = state(2);
  z = state(3);
  w = state(4);

  % t1 = (x << 11)
  t1 = bitand(bitshift(x,11),hex2dec('ffffffff'));

  % t = x ^ (x << 11)
  t = bitxor(x,t1);

  x = y;
  y = z;
  z = w;

  % t2 = (t ^ (t >> 8))
  t2 = bitxor(t, bitshift(t,-8));

  % t3 = w ^ (w >> 19)
  t3 = bitxor(w, bitshift(w,-19));

  % w = w ^ (w >> 19) ^ (t ^ (t >> 8))
  w = bitxor(t3, t2);

  state = [x y z w];
end
```

You need to pass state in to xor128 every time you use it.  I've written a "tester" function which simply returns a vector with random numbers.  I tested 1000 numbers output by this function against values output by cpp with gcc and it is perfect.

```
function [ v ] = txor( iterations )
%TXOR test xor128, returns vector v of length iterations with random number
% output from xor128

% output
v = zeros(iterations,1);

state = [123456789, 362436069, 521288629, 88675123];


i = 1;

while i <= iterations
    disp(i);

    [t,state] = xor128(state);
    v(i) = t;

    i = i + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be very careful assuming that two different implementations of pseudo random generators (even though based on the same algorithms) produce the same result. There could be that one of the implementations use some sort of tweak, hence producing different results. If you need two equal "random" distributions I suggest you either precalculate a sequence, store and access from both C++ and Matlab or create your own generator. It should be fairly easy to implement MT19937 if you use the pseudocode on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister).

Take care ensuring that both your Matlab and C++ code runs on the same architecture (that is, both runs on either 32 or 64-bit) - using a 64 bit integer in one implementation and a 32 bit integer in the other will lead to different results.