# Are there any same seed for Matlab Random and C++ Random?

Tags: c++, matlab, random, random-seed

I tried `std::mt19937 gen(2007)` in c++ and `RandStream.create('mt19937ar','seed',2007)` in Matlab. I have also tried different structures, but I couldn't find a specific seed structure to find the same random numbers between Matlab and c++. How can I handle this?

Comment: What function you use in MATLAB to get the random numbers?

Comment: I'm using `gamrnd` and `randn` functions in MATLAB.

Answer (score 3):

*You want a random generator to be deterministic and work the same way in two distinct implementations.*

There is no guarantee that Matlab and c++::std implementations will generate same results. Although it would be reasonable to think that they should - it is the same algorithm after all. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) there are flavors to the implementations. Most noteworthy is the difference between 32 and 64 bit implementation that produces different results.

To overcome this obstacle generate the numbers in one tool and then use the same sequence in the other. Or use your own algorithm - some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829499/how-to-let-boostrandom-and-matlab-produce-the-same-random-numbers).

Answer (score 1):

The difference (most likely) stems from the use of *uniformly-distributed pseudo-random* numbers in C++, while MATLAB code uses *normally-distributed pseudo-random* numbers. Try `rand`/`randi` instead `randn` in the MATLAB code (i.e. unformly-distributed integers instead of normally distributed doubles).

More on MATLAB side of the story: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/random-number-generation.html